# Making two distinct apps (root version and rootless version) or put the code in one single app?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, project

I have an android app that currently performs some tasks (heavy tasks since I am using openCV) with the use of root permissions.
At the moment I have two different apps but it gets boring handling two projects.
After a while it gets killed by the os.
Now I want to put also the option for rootless version.

So the code of the Threads would look like something like this:

```
void performTasks(Option option)
{
if(Option.ROOT)
rootTasks();
else
rootlessTasks();
}
```

Of course I would need to adjust stuff inside the Service classes and MainActivity.
So I would like your suggestion if putting everything into a project would decrease efficiency regarding memory-consumption. What is your advice?

Comment: You can have one project with two flavors, one for root and one for non-root. https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants

Comment: @Robert thanks for the reply! But that would make my app "heavier" and therefore more prone to be killed by the system?

Comment: No, you simply have two apps that share large parts of it's code. For each flavor you have separate folders where you can include code or assets. And in the end you execute one gradle command and get APKs for each flavor.

Comment: @Robert do you have an example I can look at, where there is the shared code, the code for FLAVOR_1 and code for FLAVOR_2?

Comment: Flavors are a very basic concept of Android Studio/Gradle projects. There are plenty of examples online: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+flavor+example

Comment: @Robert please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76380803/sharing-code-for-root-version-and-rootless-version-with-flavors